# Python Avoid overwriting variables

Tags: python, oop

So I am making a text game in python 2.7.9 and when you adopt a dog I would normally do something like this:

```
Jim = Dog("Jim")
```

But I created a while true loop which has an option that you can choose which adopts a dog. I can create it using their input but I can't just make the same variable = `Dog("Name")` since it would override their other dog. How would I do this?

Comment: Remember to accept (the green checkmark) what you think is the best answer

Comment: I know it says I have to wait 5 minutes.

Comment: Accepted @PythonMaster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to make a list instead:

```
Jim = []
while True:
    #*insert code here*
    Jim.append(Dog("name"))
```